# Jython does not load PYTHONPATH into sys.path

Tags: python, path, jython

According to what I've read, sys.path should be set by PYTHONPATH. In Python, it works that way, but not in Jython. I can circumvent with `-Dpython.path=...` but I'd like to know why Jython isn't playing nicely.

```
qa@Scantron:/tmp/pip-build-qa/robotframework> echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/lib64/python2.7
qa@Scantron:/tmp/pip-build-qa/robotframework> jython
Jython 2.2.1 on java1.7.0_17
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/share/jython/Lib', '__classpath__']
>>> ^D
qa@Scantron:/tmp/pip-build-qa/robotframework> jython -Dpython.path=/usr/lib64/python2.7
Jython 2.2.1 on java1.7.0_17
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/share/jython/Lib', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '__classpath__']
```

Comment: Note that you're mixing up "Python" the language with "CPython" the implementation of it. See [here](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html#implementations). `PYTHONPATH` is a feature of CPython, as you can see [here](http://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#PYTHONPATH). Of course it's also a feature of PyPy and IronPython, but that still doesn't make it a feature of Python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jython does not use PYTHONPATH: you can see [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jython/mailman/message/11533957/) a discussion.

From 2.5 onwards there is a variable that does the same: JYTHONPATH. Before that you can use the trick you already know.

Source: [Jython and PYTHONPATH](http://stefaanlippens.net/jython_and_pythonpath)